# get an url parameter when using form wizard

Tags: django

is there a way to get a parameter passed in my url when i use a form wizard ?

```
        url(r'^foo/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/add_bar/$',
        AddBarWizard.as_view([AddBarForm1, AddBarForm2,
        AddBarForm3], template_name='add-Bar.html'),
        name='add_bar'),
```

overriding the get() method, i have my request, but GET is empty, and nothing in the debug gives me the slug i'm waiting on.

Any idea ?

Comment: please show your overridden  get() method

Comment: nothing special ....    
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddBarWizard, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: then what do you expect in GET, and where do you check your `slug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apologize, my slug is in my kwargs not in the request.GET Oo

then, i'm ok, i've my slug :)